# Automate Python Scripts Scraping with Task Scheduler

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, screen-scraping

I'm trying to running my Python Scripts every day , I need a way to run my Python Scripts periodically and automatically. first I'm trying to make bat file but it always failed.. I don't know why. FYI I got 2 python exe and its makes me confuse to choose what should I use, so I try in two place but both failed.
[image: bat 1]

[image]

because its failed, I tried another way which fills the arguments and starts like this, but it's failed too, when I'm trying to run the task, it's just always show command prompt and immediately closed but didn't do anything, I'm trying with ps1 too but its the same.

[image: error 3]

i tried to execute the command **python emas_.py** like alperindo said but its stil gives me error
[image: error in command]

here's my code in `python`

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.indexmundi.com/commodities/?commodity=gold&months=300"
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table', {"class": "tblData"})
rows = table.find_all('tr')
data = []
for row in rows[1:]:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['month', 'price', 'change'])
result['month'] = pd.to_datetime(result["month"])
result.to_csv("emas_.csv", index=False)

df = pd.read_csv("emas_.csv")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)
print(df)
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = 'MSHULHAN\SQLEXPRESS'

database = 'daming'

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + server + '/' + database + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server')

#engine = create_engine('mysql://root:@localhost/daming') # enter your password and database names here

col_names = ["month", "price", "change"]
df = pd.read_csv("emas_.csv",sep=',',quotechar='\'',encoding='utf8', names=col_names,skiprows = 1) # Replace Excel_file_name with your excel sheet name
df.to_sql('emas',con=engine,index=False,if_exists='replace') # Replace Table_name with your sql table name
```

Comment: I think the start in option is what caused the problem. Try to use the same directory as where the program file is located.

Comment: program file means emas_.py right ? emas_.py is in shulhan folder

Comment: in my case, i used a bat file to run the python file and just automate the bat file. Before automating the script, just run the task first manually in the task scheduler and check if it's running or not. If it's not, there is a huge chance the program is wrong.

Comment: yeah ive already tried to make bat file but its always error..

Comment: Hmm, where is the error? Can you send me the screenshot of the settings?

Comment: I don't have experience with this but I can recommend something that is very easy to use. I use cronjobs to run python scripts automatically on Linux, for windows you can use python-crontab. ["https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab/"]("python-crontab")

Comment: Make sure to check the run only when user is logged on. Also make sure in the conditions tab, uncheck the start task only if the computer is on AC power. Make sure the trigger condition is valid too and try to run it with the highest privileges checked

Comment: i tried write the executable script with the format C:\Users\shulhan\anaconda3\python.exe"C:\Users\shulhan\emas_.py"
and run it but the result always error like in my question

Comment: yes unfortunately cron job has a limit too such as it doesn't have the option to run the program when the computer is logged on.

Comment: In a command line located at ``C:\Users\shulhan`` execute the command ``python emas_.py`` and tell us if that worked.

Comment: @Alperino the result is an error..i will give the screenshot in above

Comment: Okay, that new error message tells me that ``python`` is found from the command line and it is not your ``Anaconda``-version, but ``python36``. The error message looks to me as if your installation of the ``pandas``-package is corrupted. Given that having 2 separate python-installations is a constant potential source of conflict as well, I would strongly advise you to remove both installations first, then reinstall only one of them to have a clean setup. My recommendation is the ``Anaconda``-version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NSSM for that: https://nssm.cc/

It will install your Python script as a Windows service. Just make sure that in the `Application` tab, you enter the path to your Python in the `Path` field and your Python script in the `Arguments` field. Enter valid paths in the `Error` and `Output` field in the `I/O` tab to be able to debug if the script doesn't start right away.